# Error with declaring struct pointer

Tags: c, gcc, avr, avr-gcc

I'm trying to implement a config reader and writer on my microcontroller (using AVR-GCC), and am running into some compilation errors, specifically:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token
```

in my main file. The code causing this is:

```
#include "cfg.h"

struct config_t* config;
config.temp = TEMP_C;
config.precision = 9;
config.time = 0;

config_read(config);
```

Contents of `cfg.h`:

```
#ifndef CFG_h
#define CFG_h

#include <avr/eeprom.h> 
#include <inttypes.h>

#define TEMP_C 0
#define TEMP_F 1
#define TEMP_K 2

typedef struct config_t {
    uint8_t temp;
    uint8_t precision;
    int32_t time;
} config_t;

void config_read(struct config_t * config);
void config_write(const struct config_t * config);

#endif
```

and contents of `cfg.c`:

```
#include "cfg.h"

void config_read(struct config_t* config) {
    eeprom_read_block((void*)&config, (void*)(0), sizeof(config_t));
}

void config_write(const struct config_t* config) {
    eeprom_write_block((const void*)&config, (void*)(0), sizeof(config_t));
}
```

Comment: D'oh! Turns out I thought I had put this code in the main method but I hadn't. Still a very cryptic error message though.

Comment: All the answers to this question point out different errors, yet they are all correct

Answer (score 2):

```
struct config_t* config;
```

Issue: config is uninitialized variable. You need to use malloc to create an object for config_t struct

```
config.temp = TEMP_C;
config.precision = 9;
config.time = 0;
```

Issue: As config_t is a pointer, you can access the methods or variables of config_t struct using " -> " operator not " . " operator.

Like:

```
config->temp = TEMP_C;
config->precision = 9;
config->time = 0;

config_read(config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `struct config_t*`, you should use arrows instead of dots when initializing your `config` variable.

Comment: Now the error messages have changed to `error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '->' token`. I also tried `struct config_t* config = (config_t*)malloc(sizeof(config_t));` but it made no difference.

Comment: are you sure that this is this part of the code that causes error messages ? Because i don't see what is wrong in this 4 lines. You should try @MattMcNabb answer below, so that you don't have to use pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The `config_read` function is for *reading* config. It does not make sense to set members of `config` and call that. Instead, do:

```
struct config_t config;
config_read(&config);
```

It would make sense to set variables when writing the config:

```
struct config_t config = { 0 };
config.temp = TEMP_C;
config.precision = 9;
config.time = 0;
config_write(&config);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Typedef i.e

```
typedef struct config_t {
    uint8_t temp;
    uint8_t precision;
    int32_t time;
} config_t;
```

Its not necessary that you use always **struct** while using the structure  , and when u are using pointer to access structure members you have to use "config_t->member of structure" instead of config_t.member of structure